# How to convert single-line JSON to multi-line?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I'm copy-pasting JSON from a server log into Postman. The JSON in the server log is single-line like this:

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2}
```

but I want it to be multi-line like this:

```
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
```

Is there a way to do this in Postman or elsewhere other than manually?

Comment: this process is called JSON beautify and is available in almost all popular programming languages

Answer (score 2):

Postman has a button "Beautify" in the top right corner. Click it to be happy.
[image: Postman Beautify demo]

Comment: This is how I do it all the time manually  when doing a copy and paste to postman, upvoted as correct

Comment: `Ctrl+B` or `Cmd+B` would also do this, it would also format code in the scripts sandbox.

Comment: @djmonki Thank you very much for beautifing my answer. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about postman but in VS Code you can format document just
" right-click mouse btn in VScode > format document with > JSON Language Feature " although it works only if its fully JSON file not js.

sorry I want to write it in a comment but I don't have many reputations

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the JSON, then stringify it again:

```js
const json = `{"a": 1, "b": 2}`;

const res = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json), 0, 2)
console.log(res)
```